# Sequence of functions and improper integrals

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function

> Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of $\textbf{continuous}$ real valued functions defined on $[0, \infty)$. Suppose $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ for all $x \in [0,\infty)$ and that $f$ is integrable. Then
>
> a) $\int_0^\infty f_n(x)\;dx \rightarrow \int_0^\infty f(x)\; dx$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$
>
> b) If $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $[0,\infty)$, then $\int_0^1f_n(x)\;dx \rightarrow \int_0^1 f(x)\; dx$
>
> c) If $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $[0,\infty)$, then $\int_0^\infty f_n(x)\;dx \rightarrow \int_0^\infty f(x)\; dx$
>
> d) If $\int_0^1 \vert f_n(x- f(x) \vert dx \rightarrow 0$, then$f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$

b) is true, since , if $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $[0,\infty)$, then it is also uniformly convergent in $[0,1]$, so by a familiar result on integration, $f$ is continuous and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x)\; dx=\int_0^1 f(x)\;dx$

What about others? Any hint must be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure there is no monotonicity or boundedness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f_n(x)=\frac 1 {n(1+|x|)}$ and $f(x)=0$. Then $f_n \to f$ uniformly but $\int f_n(x) \, dx =\infty$ for all $n$. Hence a) and c) are false.

d) is also false:

Let
$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
nx&(0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{n})\\
1 &(x> \frac{1}{n})\\
\end{cases}$$

Let $f(x)=1$ for all $x$. Then $$\int_0^{1} |f_n(x)-f(x)|\, dx=\frac {1} {2n} \to 0$$ but $$\sup \{|f_n(x)-f(x)|:x \in [0,1]\} \geq |f_n(0)-f(0)|=1$$ for all $n$, so $f_n$ does not tend to $f$ uniformly.

Comment: welp, this is a pretty comprehensive answer and I'm deleting mine. +1

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: Thank you !

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: What is the idea behind for this type of counter examples? Actually, for the first time to me, I try to eliminate a) and c) with $f_n(x)=xe^{-nx^2}$.But it does't work , because it is uniformly converges to $f(x)=0$ on $\Bbb{R}$ but still  satisfies a) and c). Thats why In cannot conclude anything. Super example. thanks! +1

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: Why we put a absolute sign of $x$ here?  For this problem, I think we don't need the absolute sign of $x$, because $x \in [0, \infty)$. I think ,you put a absolute sign of $x$ for answer the more general problem. That is, your counter example still works even the domain is $\Bbb{R}$. That means,your counter example still works with the upper limit of the integral is $\infty$ and the lower limit of the integral is $- \infty$ . Am I right?

Comment: @ki3i: Yes, the absolute value of the integral  is $\frac{1}{2n}$. Thanks for the edit!

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: I edit your answer for the more comfortable view. If you don't like it, kindly edit again!

Comment: @LearningMathematics Thanks for editing. And absolute value sign was not necessary.